# a question on bounds of complex derivative at particular point

Tags: complex-analysis

Could any one tell me which of the following are correct?

$1$. There exists a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=2$

$2.$ There exists a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ with $f(3/4)=3/4$ and $f'(2/3)=3/4$

$3.$ There exists a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ with $f(3/4)=-3/4$ and $f'(3/4)=-3/4$

$4.$ There exists a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ with $f(1/2)=-1/2$ and $f'(1/4)=1$

Well, I used the formula $|f'(z)|\le {1-|f(z)|^2\over 1-|z|^2}$ and got $1,3$ but how about other two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Contradicts Schwarz Lemma.
2. Can happen. Consider a homothety with center $3/4$, that is, $f(z)=3/4+c(z-3/4)$ where $0<c<1$.
3. As in 2, but take $-f$.
4. The Schwarz inequality that you have written implies $|f(1/4)|\le 1/4$. Also, the hyperbolic distance $|a-b|/|1- a\bar b|$ does not increase under $f$. It follows that $f(1/4)$ must be equal to $-1/4$; otherwise the hyperbolic distance between $f(1/4)$ and $f(1/2)=-1/2$ would be greater than the distance between $1/4$ and $1/2$. Equality is attained only if $f$ is a Möbius transformation. But the Möbius transformation sending $1/2\mapsto -1/2$ and $1/4\mapsto -1/4$ is simply $z\mapsto -z$, which has derivative $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Pre- and postcompose $f$ with suitable automorphisms to transfer the problem to one about functions $\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ with $f(0)=0$ and use Schwarz' lemma.